# Detect hidden/invisible watermark in videos

Tags: watermark, steganography

Lately, I have been interested in Watermark & steganography.

And as a part of research i am working on, i have a mp4 video file that has a hidden/invisible Watermark.

My question is is there an easy/simple way/tool (that you experienced) to detect the hidden/invisible Watermark in videos ?

Comment: Your question is asking for tools, which is off-topic for SO. It's also a very broad question, because the best we can do is suggest various methods of steganalysis without having a prior way to say which one will work.

Comment: Could you tell me what is your algorithm for embedding an watermark in the video, as I am very interested in it?

Answer (score 0):

I would compare each frame to the previous frame and then look for pixels that have changed. Then compare the amount that the pixels changed relative to their neighbours. And keep track of where the pixels consistently change by a slightly different amount to their neighbours. Similar to what I do here to detect rapid eye movements in the dark: https://lsdbase.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/wingless-drone1.gif?w=245